# Jquery set second tr start,first td disabled,but use attr("disabled",true) no effect

Tags: jquery, html

I want to set these td disabled:
[image]

I use this code:

```
$("#table_reach_condition_appoint tbody tr:gt(0) td:eq(0)").attr("disabled",true);
```

But there is no effect,why?

My whole code at [here](https://jsfiddle.net/81tb392o/1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the combinaison of [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) and [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child), you can make sure you do not select the first row... And that you keep only the second `td` in the resulting collection.

Then you have to use an [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) loop to target the `input` inside of each `td`.

And finally, you should change the property instead of the attribute.

```
$("#table_reach_condition_appoint tr:not(:nth-child(1)) td:nth-child(2)").each(function(){
  $(this).find("input").prop("disabled",true);
});
```

Your [Fiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/juksrz5d/).

Comment: Thank you sir,but why `attr` has no effect?

Comment: 1) `.attr()` can have an effect... But it is best to use `.prop()`. 2) In your code, it had no effect because you applyed it on a `td`. It's on the `input` inside it has to be applyed on. 3) Trying to change a property or an attribute on a collection of multiple elements will only work on the first one. That's why the each loop is needed.